# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 1206: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I have an array `W` containing float numbers.

```
W.dtype = float32 
type(W) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Then I `pickle.dump()` it into a `mr.pkl` file,

```
pickle.dump(W, open("/home/mr.pkl", "wb"))
```

but when I load it,

```
pickle.load(open("/home/mr.pkl","rb"))
```

an error occurs:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 1206: ordinal not in range(128)

I don't know why, I was confused about it for a week, can any one help me about this? any help is appreciated, thank you a lot!

Comment: We need [mcve] to be able to help you.

Comment: It'd be really nice to have the full traceback too

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20?rq=1 or the other kazillion questions regarding this on SO.

Comment: Looking into this myself, seems to be a compatibility issue between Python versions.

Comment: thanks everyone! I found that I dump the data using python2.7 while load it by python3.5, I think it might because Pickle of these two version are not compatible.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, this code worked for me. The encoding='latin1' is the important part.

```
# read in data from pickle file created with Load_Data.py
pickle_file = 'mnist.pkl'
with open(pickle_file, 'rb') as f:
    train_set, valid_set, test_set = pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')
```

Comment: thanks Linda! I think your method works when I load data in other language, but I think my problem is not this, because W only contains float number, so I found that I dump the data using python2.7 while load it by python3.5, so it's may because Pickle of these two version are not compatible, thank you for your kind reply again!

Comment: The MNIST data set is all floats and ints, but thanks, I'll try the dump data next time.

Answer (score 0):

OK,  I find out a solution *but only in console mode*.
The steps are as followings.

1. Why and Can not import mnist_loader?   Yes, you should put your 'yourscript.py' in the same folder with mnist_loader.py
2. Why an error 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 614: ordinal not in range(128)'?   Yes, 'yourscript.py' need in the same folder with mnist_loader.py  >> Like me if you use IPython, you need download yourscript.ipynb as 'yourscript.py'
3. If uses P3.X, please rewrite something in mnist_loader.py as followings " import _pickle as Pickle" and "Pickle.load(f, encoding='latin1')"
4. When you try to print or get data from Pickle.load(...), please transfer 'zip' type from output of Pickle.load(...) as a list type like list(train_data), ...
5. In console mode,  ...in mnist_loader.py folder(in general ..\src)...>> Python yourscript.py
6. You can see it is workable.  For example:  print('len ', len(list(train_data))),  it shows 50000.

But...

**7. I still do not know why it is not workable in IPython.**